# “I'm a student at UCLA” or “I'm a student in UCLA”?

Tags: prepositions, definite-articles, prepositional-phrases

Sounds simple, but I've always been confused. I am also not sure about using the definite article, like “I'm a student in/at the UCLA.” Is that normative American English?   Thanks for your help.

Comment: Articles are not used consistently with proper names. In the Unites States, it's _a student **at** `college name`_. E.g, _a student **at** UCLA/Chicago/Harvard/Georgetown._

Comment: You might want to visit [English for Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) which is a site more suited for that kind of questions. EL&U is more biased towards academic study of the language.

Answer (score 2):

**at** is used to indicate membership, participation etc. You're a student of UCLA - you study *at* UCLA.

**in** is about location. Say, you're a student of a small private vocational school, which rents one classroom inside the UCLA campus. Then you study *in* UCLA, but not *at* UCLA.

Comment: In my experience, U.S. style is to say both "a student at" and "study at." Idiomatically, I associate "a student of" with tutelage under a specific teacher ("I'm a student of hers") or with unaccredited study ("I'm a student of the human condition").

Comment: While *at* is used for the overall institution, affiliation with units can be *in*; I'm *a student in the hotel school at Cornell University* or *a student in the mathematics program at Harvey Mudd*. I agree with SvenYarg's comment on *of* referring to the discipline for students, though with faculty one can use *of* as a differentiator: Prof. Jane Smith *of* MIT, not Prof. Jane Smith of CalTech.