# “CEO at” or “CEO of”?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is it proper to say John Smith is the CEO **of** ABC Company or John Smith is the CEO **at** ABC Company?

Comment: Definitely   CEO of:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=CEO+of%2CCEO+at&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CCEO%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CCEO%20at%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Related: *[I am an intern of/in/at 'company name'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215086)*, *[“I'm a student at UCLA” or “I'm a student in UCLA”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147223)*

Comment: @choster Your comment relates to those being indefinite (a/an) positions.

Answer (score 6):

This tends to follow a convention of whether the position is definite or indefinite.

> Ted's an important person; he's **a** CEO **at** ABC.
>   **The** CEO **of** ABC made an important statement today.

We also see "at" when highlighting a position within a subdivision of an organization.

> He's the President **of** Human Resources **at** ABC.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of a CEO "at" a company; by definition, there's only one CEO, *the* CEO *of* that company.

Comment: You probably have had no reason to refer to a CEO as an indefinite noun.  This is because there is normally only one CEO, as you point out.  In my example, the use of a is to highlight Ted's type of job: he's an executive, he's a farmhand, he's a CEO.  Another example:  "A CEO at ABC is responsible for five times as many people as as a CEO at TBS."

Comment: that last example in your comment makes much more sense to me, @Cord